# Koolgrid in php change the ItemTemplate value

Tags: php

Anyone knows about koolgrid php, I need some help with my code.
My code is:

```
include 'koolgrid.php';

$column = new GridCustomColumn();
                    $column->ItemTemplate = "{banner_urltype=='web_url' ? 'Web Url' : 'Video Url'}";
                    $column->ReadOnly = true;
                    $column->HeaderText = "Url Type";
                    $dsk->MasterTable->AddColumn($column);
```

and I want to change this line

`$column->ItemTemplate = "{banner_urltype=='web_url' ? 'Web Url' : 'Video Url'}";`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know koolgrid, but you should do this:

```
$column->ItemTemplate = banner_urltype=='web_url' ? 'Web Url' : 'Video Url';
```

Comment: Another way to solve my query to add MySQL query update.

Comment: Ok, but your line above won't work if you don't change it to what I corrected it to...

Comment: I am simply use $column->ItemTemplate = "{banner_urltype}" and in my query use "CASE" and its works done